# How to set up Drupal Commerce to sell users the ability to create/post custom nodes (ex. classified ads)?

Tags: commerce

I am currently working on a classifieds D7 site, and I would like to sell users the ability to create/post a classified ad. With D6 + Ubercart this can be done using the UC Node Checkout module (http://drupal.org/project/uc_node_checkout), and following the instructions provided on the Drupal Easy website (http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/03/event-registration-ubercart).

Is there any way implement the same functionality with D7 + Drupal Commerce?

Thank you so much

Comment: Not much help I'm afraid, but I am looking for exactly the same functionality. From what I gather you set up a Checkout Rule which publishes the node after the checkout process is complete, but, I cannot work out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Rules pretty easily.

1. Create a role with the desired permission.
2. Create a product to sell.
3. Create a rule for the checkout complete event.

   Condition is that the product you created is in the order. (I would probably create my own condition as I'm better with code than with the Rules interface, but you should be able to set this up in the Rules interface.)
   Action is to give user that owns the order the selected role.
4. There is no step 4, you're done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You can find additional answers to this question in the following links: [link](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/638) and [link](http://drupal.org/node/1215886)